# EF core - multiple cascade paths error if using data annotations and duplicate keys if using fluent APIs

Tags: entity-framework-core

My Models without foreign key annotations are;

```
Division {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Rooms> DivisionRooms { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Desks> DivisionDesks { get; set; }
}

//------------------------------------------
Rooms {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DivisionId { get; set; }
    public Division Division { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Desks> DivisionDesks { get; set; }
}   
//------------------------------------------
Desks {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int DivisionId { get; set; }
    public Division Division { get; set; }

    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; }

}
```

With fluent APIs I create indexes etc... If I add a migration for this, the code automaticaly picks the foreign keys properly and migration code is all fine. But when creating the database with Update-Database command it says;

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint etc..etc.. may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Now to add cascade restrictions, If I add foreign key definitions via fluent apis (ex:- For Desk entity)

```
builder.HasOne<Room>()
       .WithMany()
       .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoomId)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

This generates the migration script having duplicate foreign keys. But Update-Database works and creates the database with Room entity with duplicate foreign keys to other two entities.

So basically, If I use data annotations; when running update-database it complains about cascade issues and if I use fluent apis and restrict cascades it creates duplicate foreign keys.

So how can I get this model properly defined with navigation included?

Comment: So the model should be as it is? Because from my understanding a division has multiple rooms which in turn have multiple desks (unless a desk may not belong to a room where you should define a nullable int).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
builder.Entity<Division>()
       .HasMany(x=>x.DivisionDesks)
       .WithOne()
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

builder.Entity<Division>()
       .HasMany(x=>x.DivisionRooms)
       .WithOne()
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

builder.Entity<Room>()
       .HasMany(x=>x.DivisionDesks)
       .WithOne()
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

I think your issue was with how you handled `HasForeignKey` it's not the way to actually implement the one to many relation on EF Core. Also you don't user Flunter **OR** annotations. Both are working together. You use annotation to produce some basic relationships and then use fluent to construct more complex data.

Using `HasForeignKey` is what creates the duplicate one since it's already defined with your class through the naming convention.

Also as a side note the scema might not be optimal since a division has multiple rooms and each room has multiple desks. So I wouldn't place a direct navigation property from division to desk altough this is mostly about db design principles and how normalized you want them to be.